# Sticky footer not working on Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, sticky-footer

I'm working on a WordPress website, and I've run into an issue. The sticky footer I've implemented works great in every browser but Safari. I think it is some sort of padding issue because adding extra padding to the footer corrects the problem in Safari, but this causes the footer to be taller in other browsers which looks odd.

I've been struggling with getting the sticky footer right, and I thought I'd figured it out but obviously I haven't. I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I cannot sort it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the website: [gandyprinters.com/wordpress](http://gandyprinters.com/wordpress).

Thanks,
Rebecca

---EDIT---

Somehow I've managed to correct this issue. I don't know exactly at what point it corrected itself, but it has.

Thanks to everyone who gave input!! I really appreciate the time you took to respond and offer help.

Comment: looks correct on my ipad's safari in both orientations.

Comment: Hmmm that's good to know. Could it be my iMac due to its screen size?

Comment: if the page misbehave only in desktop safari you could try to run a conditional JS to fix this issue. I don't understand how come it works fine in google chrome and not in safari they are both based on webkit.

Comment: That's why I don't know how to fix it! Hmm I'll look into conditional JS. Thanks!

Comment: In my pc, I checked it 5 times, but it looks same as firefox. What is your actually problem?

Comment: Well, I had an issue where the footer was overlapping content, but I seem to have resolved it now somehow.

Comment: You should always post the code you're referring to so we can better help you.

Comment: great that you solved the issue but think this should be removed as you haven't actually provided a solution, doesn't help anyone else