# Stick Footer Fix for mobile Device using WordPress Thesis?

Tags: wordpress, footer, sticky, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm working on a WordPress website using the Thesis theme. I had my sticky footer working in Chrome, IE and Safari but as I was trying to get it to work on mobile devices everything took a turn for the worst!

So my question is, is there a sticky footer solution for WordPress that works across all browsers including mobile devices?

This stackoverflow post asks the question and their site works DOES work on mobile devices but the answer is not given on how they got it to work! [Sticky footer not working on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163080/sticky-footer-not-working-on-safari)

Any help would be appreciated! The website I am working on is: http://www.oldpueblogymnastics.com/wordpress/. You shorter page is http://www.oldpueblogymnastics.com/wordpress/parents-night-out/

```
custom_functions.php code

// sticky footer
function div_push() {
?>
<div class="push"></div>
<?php
}

function div_wrapper_start() {
?>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php
}

function div_wrapper_close() {
?>
</div><!--end wrapper-->
<?php
}

add_action('thesis_hook_after_content_area', 'div_push');
add_action('thesis_hook_before_html', 'div_wrapper_start');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_content_area', 'div_wrapper_close');
```

CSS can be seen in source.

Thanks!

Ginger